# Is there a declared meaning of the first eight bytes of .png files?

Tags: encoding, png

I am reading a code and see the following comment section in it:

```
            // We need to determine if the image is a PNG or a JPEG
            // PNGs are easier to detect because they have a unique signature (http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Structure.html)
            // The first eight bytes of a PNG file always contain the following (decimal) values:
            // 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10
```

If I look at the ASCII codes, I get the following text:

> ëPNG♪◙→◙

from which PGN is pretty clear. Is there an explanation for the other parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PNG specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature)

In ASCII it is: \211   P   N   G  \r  \n \032 \n

The first two are to make sure it is recognized as PNG ( a non-ASCII character and the P), the newline afterward is to prevent bad file transfers and the second last (CTRL-Z) character prevents DOS from displaying the file contents and the last newline is for the same reason as the first newline sequence